# Solr ngram does not match number?

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, n-gram

I'm using the standard Solr ngram field definition --

```
<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" stored="false" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- potentially word delimiter, synonym filter, stop words, NOT stemming -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- potentially word delimiter, synonym filter, stop words, NOT stemming -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="item" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="item_ngram" type="ngram" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

now "item:ipad AND item:2" finds "iPad 2", but "item_ngram:ipad AND item_ngram:2" does not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your n-grams have a minimum length of 2 (minGramSize="2"). So item_ngram:2 won't match on anything. Decrease it to 1 and you will get matches.